# How many Earthlings featured in the show have met more than two regenerations of Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

If you are with the title character in the Doctor Who series when he regenerates, you'll have seen two versions, the former and the new Doctor. Are there any Earthlings featured in the series that met more than two Doctors, and if so, who were they?

Comment: When Clara jumped into The Doctor's timeline-thingy on Trenzalore she met, or at least saw, all 11 (at the time), also later saw The War Doctor and has now met the 12th.

Comment: No one has met a Dr Who because that is the name of the series, the character is called 'The Doctor'

Comment: @JamesRyan, What about a doctor in the WHO? :D (Tying back into DW, Peter Capaldi is the newest Doctor, and he was a WHO doctor in World War Z!)

Comment: this question is bordering on being off-topic because the answer is an open-ended list; can you perhaps narrow it down to a time frame, e.g. "as of xx incarnation" or "as of xx episode"?

Comment: Rose didn't meet John Hurt's Doctor. That was an AI that was using the appearance of Rose.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an open-ended list

Comment: Edited to address open ended list issue.

Comment: Does River Song count as an Earthling for the purposes of this question? She's 1 episode away from going on the list :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. This list is not complete, but counts companions who knew more than two Doctors, or who met two Doctors out of turn (i.e., they weren’t around for his regeneration). I may have missed some, but I think this is all the obvious ones.

- **Sarah Jane Smith**: a companion of the Third and Fourth Doctors, who then meets the First, Second and Fifth in *The Five Doctors*, the Tenth Doctor in *School Reunion*, and the Eleventh Doctor in *Death of the Doctor* (SJA).
- Also in *Death of the Doctor* was **Jo Grant**, who was a companion of the Third Doctor, and met the Eleventh Doctor in *DotD*.
- **Clara Oswald** briefly saw every incarnation of the Doctor (including the War Doctor and up to Eleven) when she entered through the Doctor’s time stream. We know she met the Tenth, Eleventh and War Doctors in the 50th Anniversary Special, *The Day of the Doctor*. She also met the Twelfth after the Eleventh regenerated.

  Clara also had "echoes" living different lives in different times thanks to entering the Doctor's time stream, and different echoes met other Doctors such as the First, but it’s not clear if Clara herself “met” any other Doctor who she didn’t know already.
- **Brigadier Alastair Lethbridge-Stewart**: appears with the Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth and Seventh Doctors.

  He may also have met the Eleventh Doctor, who calls trying to see him in *The Wedding of River Song*, but is informed that he has passed away. The Tenth Doctor also made reference to him in *The Sontaran Stratagem*, so may have visited him in his final year.
  It is also *strongly* hinted at that he was turned into a Cyberman and met the twelfth in that capacity, but that was after his death, so it may not count.
- Also from UNIT, **Sergeant Benton**: works alongside the Second, Third and Fourth Doctors.
- **Peri Brown** travelled alongside the Fifth and Sixth Doctors, and also met the Second Doctor in *The Two Doctors*.
- In *The Two Doctors*, **Jamie McCrimmon**, a companion of the Second Doctor, likewise meets the Sixth Doctor.
- There’s also a charity special [*Dimensions in Time*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensions_in_Time) which ran for the 30th anniversary, which had various companions meeting a different Doctor to their own, though fans usually consider this one non-canonical.
- In *The Day of the Doctor*, **Kate Stewart**, along with UNIT scientists **Osgood** and **McGillop**, were all in the Black Archive when the War Doctor, the Tenth Doctor, and the Eleventh Doctor emerged from a painting there to stop a standoff between them and their Zygon doubles. Kate Stewart and Osgood also met the Twelfth Doctor in *Death in Heaven*.
- **Queen Elizabeth I** also met the War Doctor, Ten, and Eleven in 1562, in *The Day of the Doctor*. A member of Elizabeth's court named **[Lord Bentham](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Bentham)** also saw all three, and accused them of witchcraft, and some soldiers who did not have speaking lines onscreen were present as well (and took the Doctors to the Tower of London). A clergyman was later present at the wedding of Elizabeth and Ten, along with the War Doctor and Eleven.
- **River Song** met Ten, Eleven, and Twelve. She also says she knows all his faces, so she may have met all of him.

Comment: Nice list, just to add to it Rose Tyler met both 9 and 10

Comment: @Liath: Doesn’t Rose fall in the set of companions who only saw two Doctors because she was with him when he regenerated?

Comment: If Big Finish audio dramas are taken as canon, Romana and Leela have both met at least the Fourth and Eighth Doctors, and Charley travelled with the Sixth and Eighth Doctors.

Comment: @alexwlchan, I suppose that depends on whether you count the Moment taking on Rose's appearance for the War Doctor, or if you count Tennant's clone. (Also, I would argue that Clara saw _all_ of the doctors, including the versions that haven't been cast with actors yet -- those just weren't shown on-screen for obvious reasons.)

Comment: Of course, technically, River Song belongs on this list as well, as she has met multiple incarnations of the Doctor but not been present during the regeneration of any of them.

Comment: The Moment was definitely not Rose, or rather Rose was not experiencing The Doctor through the Moment - so she wouldn't count.

Comment: Also, Tegan, Turlough, and Susan also met multiple Doctors in *The Five Doctors*. And since the OP says "Earthlings", not "Companions", there's also Harriet Jones and Lady Cassandra (who both met Nine and Ten), for a start.

Comment: And Jo Grant also met the Second Doctor in *The Three Doctors*, I can't remember if she saw or had any interaction with the First Doctor on the Tardis monitor though (Benton and the Brigadier may have seen him as well).

Comment: Anybody mind if I mark this as Community Wiki and edit all the suggestions into the list?

Comment: The question was asking for those who met **more** than two, not two or more, so a lot of these are tangential - interesting, but not valid answers to the question.

Comment: Don't forget that Clara also met the 12th Doctor in the Christmas special.

Comment: Captain Jack, meet 9 and 10

Comment: Kate Stewart meets the war doctor, and 10 and 11 (this would also extend to Osgood and McGillop and the rest of the humans (soldiers and the Queen)).

Comment: @Roger Turlough and Susan are not Earthlings.

Comment: Queen Elizabeth met 10, 11, and War in The Day of the Doctor. Cleopatra has likely met several. 5 said he met her. 6 said he watched her. 10 intimated he'd seen her bedchamber. 11 hung out with her for sure in Dinosaurs on a Spaceship.

Comment: @OrangeDog Whoops. Good point.

Comment: William Shakespeare meets 10 in "The Shakespeare Code". He also met some Doctor at least once before "Planet of Evil" and "City of Death" (in both of which 4 talks about having met him), and he meets both 5 and 8 in various audio dramas (5 in "The Kingmaker" and 8 in "The Time of the Daleks").

Comment: @CreationEdge Dinosaurs on a Spaceship had Nefertite, not Cleopatra.

Comment: River Song may not qualify as an "Earthling" either, being neither born on Earth, being technically human, nor living on Earth for any significant proportion of her life.

Answer (score 12):

[Winston Churchill](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Winston_Churchill) has met the 2nd, 6th, 11th and probably more.

Answer (score 7):

When [Clara Oswald](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Clara_Oswald) jumped into The Doctor's timeline on Trenzalore she met, or at least saw, all 11 (at the time).

> Still, this act of bravery by the "ordinary girl" — the 21st century original — created the "impossible girl" who so intrigued the Doctor, largely by repeatedly dying in front of him. It meant that the Doctor met her out of synch with his own timeline, as had been the case with River and Mel. The Eleventh Doctor alone met a couple of versions of her before meeting the original: Oswin Oswald, a hyper-intelligent crew member onboard the Alaska who got converted into a Dalek; and a barmaid-cum-nanny called Clara Oswin Oswald in Victorian era London. Though her assistance mostly went unnoticed by Doctors prior to the Eleventh, she met and subtly helped them all. Significantly, she was able to attract the attention of the First Doctor and convince him to steal the "right" TARDIS when he first left Gallifrey with Susan.

Following these events (in [The Day of the Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Doctor_%28TV_story%29)) she saw The War Doctor, and did not recognize him.

> Clara: But I never saw that one. I saw all of you. Eleven faces. All of them you.
>
> The Doctor: I said he was me. I never said he was the Doctor.
>
> Clara: But I don't understand.
>
> The Doctor: My name, my real name, that is not the point. The name I chose is the Doctor. The name you choose, it's like, it's like a promise you make. He's the one who broke the promise. {Clara collapses} Clara? Clara! He is my secret.

Then, after the events of [The Time of the Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Time_of_the_Doctor_%28TV_story%29), when The Doctor is given a new set of regenerations, she meets the newest (12th) Doctor.

**Clara has met or seen them all**, excepting the *non-canon* TV doctor (Peter Cushing) from The Dalek movies: [Dr. Who and the Daleks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Who_and_the_Daleks) and [Dr. Who : Daleks' Invasion Earth 2150 AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daleks_%E2%80%93_Invasion_Earth:_2150_A.D.).

Comment: @alexwlchan obviously has a better answer (as mine was too specific) but I'm going to leave mine up anyway in case someone wants a little more detail on The Impossible Girl. +1 for Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Since The 2023 David Tennant Ncuti Gatwa Specials, we can add Mel who met 8,14 and Ncuti (15 or 1 depending on how you count.)

Answer (score -5):

Peri met the 5th, 6th, and 7th incarnations of the Doctor, and even traveled with them. Clara technically met with all 13 incarnations of the Doctor, but traveled with 13 and 14 (11 and 12). Sarah traveled with the 3rd and 4th Doctor, but met the 10th Doctor.

Comment: This answer repeats portions of the @alexwlchan answer with less detail and no additional information.

Comment: Since The 2023 David Tennant Ncuiti Gatwa Specials, we can add Mel who met 8,14 and Ncuti (15 or 1)