# Were any Companions with more than one non-consecutive Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Doctor Who* (either the old seasons or the revived series), were there ever any people who were Companions of two **non-consecutive** Doctors? So not people like Rose (9th and 10th) and Clara (11th and 12th), but something more like if Donna (10th) reappeared in the show now (12th).

Comment: Ugh. Tell me Donna isn't coming back.

Comment: Related, but I don’t think it’s a dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52122/3567

Comment: @Richard What's wrong with Donna? :-( She was my favourite Companion!

Comment: @randal'thor - You're dead to me.

Comment: @randal'thor - I can't stand the woman. She thinks she's funny (she's not). She was bearable as a "joke companion" for the xmas episode but I genuinely thought the BBC were taking the mick when they announced she would be a recurring character.

Comment: @Richard: that was my reaction at the first, but I really came around to her.  She’s infuriating as a person (I’d hate to sit next to her at dinner), but she makes for very good stories.

Comment: I am with @Richard donna was poorly cast. I ended up not watching the series after the first few episodes.

Comment: Do you count the Brigadier as a companion?

Comment: @EricLippert I'm not really familiar with old Who, so don't really know enough to say whether he should count or not.

Comment: @eric he was more of a recurring character. His appearance in the new Who series was a cameo (and not even played by the same actor).

Comment: @richard Who other than Courtney played the Brigadier?

Comment: @Richard lol, for me that was the opposite: I was disappointed that she stayed for just one episode, and I was then very happy to notice her coming back for a whole season!

Comment: @EricLippert Jeremiah Krage.

Comment: @Richard [Sorry to disappoint you!](http://www.entertainmentdaily.co.uk/david-tennant-and-catherine-tate-reuniting-for-doctor-who-specials/)

Comment: @randal'thor  -I just vomited into my mouth a little.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "companion" (ie sole companion? for how long?), one example is **[Sarah Jane Smith](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Sarah_Jane_Smith)**. She met 1, 2, 5, 7 & 8,  travelled with 3 & 4 and had adventures with 10 & 11 (not to mention [her own adventures](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sarah_Jane_Adventures)).

Answer (score 22):

Depending on your definition of a "Companion", you may wish to add [K9](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/K9) to your list.

He traveled extensively with the 4th Doctor, then made a series of cameo appearances (alongside Sarah Jane Smith) in the 10th Doctor serials.

Answer (score 5):

If you count the audios, Charley Pollard traveled with the Eighth Doctor, then traveled with the Sixth Doctor.

Comment: Yep!  In that order.